# CMake: Managing a list of source files

Tags: cmake

The problem I'm having at the moment is that I simply wish to manage my list of source files by grabbing everything and removing the few odds and ends that I do not need. I was hoping that Cmake provided nice built-in tools for this.

So I might start with:

```
file(GLOB A "Application/*.cpp")
```

I feel like I want to create another list of files to be removed and I want to tell CMake: Remove from list A items that are in list B.

If this were Python I might do something like:

```
C = [f for f in A if f not in B]
```

I may have screwed that syntax up but I'm wondering if there is built-in support for managing these lists of files in a more elegant way?

Even if I could do something like my Python example, A is list of absolute paths so constructing B is clunky.

And why absolute paths anyway? It seems like this will break your build as soon as you relocate the source.

Comment: Why is A a list of absolute paths?  Use relative ones.  Also don't forget you don't have to type the paths to make a hardcoded list.  Just do something like: ls >> CMakeLists.txt, then rearrange with your favorite editor.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that by using the [list command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:list) with the REMOVE_ITEM option:

```
list(REMOVE_ITEM <list> <value> [<value> ...])
```

Have a look:

```
file(GLOB FOO *)
set (ITEMS_TO_REMOVE "item;item2;item3")
message(STATUS "FOO is ${FOO}")
list(REMOVE_ITEM FOO ${ITEMS_TO_REMOVE})
message(STATUS "FOO is now ${FOO}")
```

Keep in mind that the paths returned by `file(GLOB)` are absolute, you might want to build your list of items to remove by prepending `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}` to each one of them:

```
set (ITEMS_TO_REMOVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/item;
                      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/item2;
                      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/item3")
```

Comment: It's not obvious in the official cmake documentation that multiple values can be passed in to `REMOVE_ITEM` like this as semicolon delimited.  Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 4):

If you like Python, you can generate your list of source files with [execute_process](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aexecute_process). There is also possiblity to work with [lists](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3alist).

But I would recommend you to "hardcode" your list of source files.
[File command documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3afile) states:

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.