# Is it possible to add a whole directory of source files to CMake command add_executable?

Tags: cmake

The [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html) of `CMake`'s `add_executable` gives the following specification of the command:

```
add_executable(<name> [WIN32] [MACOSX_BUNDLE]
               [EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL]
               source1 [source2 ...])
```

I now have a rather large project with a lot of sources and was wondering if it is possible to add a directory as a parameter for `add_executable` instead of specifying each source file individually? If not, are there any best practices or recommendations on how to approach this situation? I can't imagine the only way this would work is by adding each source file individually? How would this work for (really) large projects then, this doesn't seem like an elegant approach...

Comment: `FILE GLOB` maybe and a variable containing the sourcefile list after?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CMake: Managing a list of source files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213996/cmake-managing-a-list-of-source-files)

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is indeed to list all files manually.

In particular, the CMake docs [warn about using GLOB](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/file.html) for this purpose:

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from
>   your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is
>   added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to
>   ask CMake to regenerate.

This point is somewhat controversial, as many developers prefer that the build system just adjusts automatically to newly added files. The price for this automation is an increase in fragility of the build scripts.

You will have to remember to manually re-run CMake whenever files were added or removed. You also have to ensure that the physical layout of the files on disk matches the logical layout of the projects that you want to build. The latter point is arguably the bigger problem here. By decoupling the build system from the files on disk you add an additional safety net, but you have to pay for it with increased build script maintenance costs.

The biggest disadvantage of the explicit approach is imho that if you forget to add a new file to the CMakeLists, you might be wondering over weird linker errors for a while before realizing your mistake. I personally find the maintenance overhead for this approach acceptable. Sure, you will have a lengthy filelist in your build script, but you do not have to touch it that often and the changes will usually be trivial.

Since this point is somewhat controversial, I won't blame you if you want to use a GLOB for your project. Just be aware of the consequences and be prepared that all the cool kids will laugh at you if your build breaks one day because of this.